# Young adult book fantasy series featuring a knight that receives a blood transfusion, and the Aztec god, Huītzilōpōchtli, as one of the antagonists

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm trying to find a book series I remember reading as a kid (9-12 years old, around 2000). There are several distinct memories of the book, but I have no clue about the plot.

1. The Aztec god, Huītzilōpōchtli, was one of the antagonists.
2. Sir Galahad (I think it was Galahad, but it totally could've just been a random knight) was bleeding to death and the main female character used a sterilized pen to transfuse him with her O+ blood.

Answer (score 11):

This is surely the [Everworld series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41844-everworld) by K.A. Applegate. From the summary on Goodreads:

> There is a place that shouldn’t exist. But does. And there are
> creatures that shouldn’t exist. But do. Welcome to a land where all of
> your dreams and nightmares are very real—and often deadly. Welcome to
> Everworld.
>
> David’s life was pretty normal. School. Friends. Girlfriend. Actually,
> Senna was probably the oddest aspect of his life. She was beautiful.
> Smart. But there was something very different about her. Something
> strange.
>
> And on the day it began, everything happened so quickly. One moment,
> Senna was with him. The next, she was swallowed up by the earth, her
> screams echoing from far, far away. David couldn’t just let her go.
> Neither could the others. His friends—and hers. So, they followed. And
> found themselves in a world they could have never imagined.
>
> Now they have to find Senna and get home without losing their lives.
> Or their minds. Or both…

The series involves, among other things, Arthurian knights, Vikings, the Greek gods, and many different mythologies. Huitzilopoctli appears in the second book, *[Land of Loss](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/279671.Land_of_Loss)*, where the children join a band of Vikings in fighting against the Aztec gods. They are defeated:

> Huitzilopoctli reached down and raised a tiny, toylike Mjolnir.    It
> looked ridiculous in his massive hand. And I guess he thought so, too,
> because he held it up, displayed it for all to see

and have to escape before Huitzilopoctli  eats their hearts.

The blood transfusion scene you remember occurs in book 3, *[Enter the Enchanted](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/279664.Enter_the_Enchanted)* which introduces Merlin and the knights of the Round Table. Sir Galahad is badly wounded in battle and April, one of the children who were pulled into the Everworld, gives him a transfusion of her blood, making use of her 20th century medical know-how. After the successful transfer Galahad worries that having female blood in his veins might affect him:

> “I feared that having your blood flowing in my veins would unman me,”
> Galahad said with a shadow of his old smile. “Now I see that it can
> only make me more bold.”
>
> I didn’t know what to say to that. It wasn’t the kind of compliment
> you hear very often. A perfect knight doesn’t come up every day and
> compliment me on my blood.